# Почему размывает градиент?

Tags: css, css3

Подскажите почему размывает линию градиента?
Переход делаю резкий, в браузерах mac os все четко а на винде в хроме размазывает.

Винда:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Osx:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.wrapper {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(80deg,#5d466f 0%,#5d466f 52%,#5d466f 52%,#f7f9ff 52.05%,#f7f9ff 100%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(80deg,#5d466f 0%,#5d466f 52%,#5d466f 52%,#f7f9ff 52.05%,#f7f9ff 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(80deg,#5d466f 0%,#5d466f 52%,#5d466f 52%,#f7f9ff 52.05%,#f7f9ff 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(80deg,#5d466f 0%,#5d466f 52%,#5d466f 52%,#f7f9ff 52.05%,#f7f9ff 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(10deg,#5d466f 0%,#5d466f 52%,#5d466f 52%,#f7f9ff 52.05%,#f7f9ff 100%);
    height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'></div>
```

Comment: Выясните для начала, какая операционная система (версия) и версия браузера.

Comment: @VenZell у меня в последней Windows 10 с последним Хромом - край зубчиками. И в сафари на MacOS 10.12 через VMware - тоже так.

Comment: @VenZell такое вот кино: http://take.ms/ZZjW5

Comment: @KAGGDesign У меня на семерке то же самое в последнем Chrome

Comment: Эх странно это.  может у него расширение в хроме стоит какое-нибудь.

Comment: internet explorer - зубчиками но более маленькими (чем у firefox), кажутся слегка размытыми.

Comment: Тут, скорее всего, вина браузера. В опере на Windows 10 все окей

Answer (score 4):

Mozilla Firefox при 45deg без зубчиков. Наверное за отображение отвечает браузер.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.wrapper {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(80deg,#5d466f 0%,#5d466f 52%,#5d466f 52%,#f7f9ff 52.05%,#f7f9ff 100%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(80deg,#5d466f 0%,#5d466f 52%,#5d466f 52%,#f7f9ff 52.05%,#f7f9ff 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(80deg,#5d466f 0%,#5d466f 52%,#5d466f 52%,#f7f9ff 52.05%,#f7f9ff 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(80deg,#5d466f 0%,#5d466f 52%,#5d466f 52%,#f7f9ff 52.05%,#f7f9ff 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(45deg,#5d466f 0%,#5d466f 52%,#5d466f 52%,#f7f9ff 52.05%,#f7f9ff 100%);
    height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'></div>
```

**Добавлено**

В некоторых случаях края линий становятся зубчатыми, причем их отрисовка зависит от браузера: Chrome справляется лучше, в Firefox видны ступеньки. Чтобы сделать край плавным, можно сделать стык между цветами не четкий, а размытый, шириной 1-2%. Также следует помнить о проблеме с прозрачными цветами в Firefox — это решается использованием нужного оттенка с полной прозрачностью.

http://yoksel.github.io/css-patterns/

Чтобы граница градиента была ровной, без зубчиков, границу прозрачности нужно делать чуть дальше, чем точка остановки цвета.

https://codepen.io/yoksel/pen/eolqw

**Попробуй так:**

```
$transparent: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);

$color-1: #5d466f;

$size: 100%;
$big-size: $size*1;
$min: 0;
$max: $size*0.668;

.wrapper  {
    height: 500px;
    width: 100%;

  background: 
    linear-gradient(10deg,
      $color-1 $max, 
      $transparent $max*1.005
      ) 

    ;
  background-size:  $big-size $big-size;
  }

<div class='wrapper'></div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Можно убрать лишний `#5d466f 52%` должно помочь

```css
.wrapper {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(80deg,#5d466f 0%,#5d466f 52%,#f7f9ff 52.05%,#f7f9ff 100%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(80deg,#5d466f 0%,#5d466f 52%,#f7f9ff 52.05%,#f7f9ff 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(80deg,#5d466f 0%,#5d466f 52%,#f7f9ff 52.05%,#f7f9ff 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(80deg,#5d466f 0%,#5d466f 52%,#f7f9ff 52.05%,#f7f9ff 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(10deg,#5d466f 0%,#5d466f 52%,#f7f9ff 52.05%,#f7f9ff 100%);
    height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'></div>
```

Comment: не помогло.....